# Convert string to custom data type Haskell

Tags: parsing, haskell, custom-type

I've created a custom datatype Expr

```
type Name = String
type Domain = [Integer]
data Expr = Val Integer
 | Var Name
 | Expr :+: Expr
 | Expr :-: Expr
 | Expr :*: Expr
 | Expr :/: Expr
 | Expr :%: Expr
    deriving Eq
```

I need to create a parser that creates a datatype Expr from an string without using a parser library in Haskell.

I've created the parser for the initial string that accepts a string of the form "2*a+b" and converts it to the form "Val 2 :*: Var  "a"  :+: Var "b" " that is accepted by the Expr but this is where I don't know that to do in order to go further. My problem is that I don't know how to create an Expr from a such a string without a parser library.

Comment: Why do you not want to use a parser library?

Comment: Because I am not allowed to use it.

Comment: What are the constraints of this homework exercise?

Comment: This is the only one.I have this customType Expr that has for example the following form Val 2 :*: Var "a" :+: Var "b". But now I a required to make as imple string like 2*a+b to Val 2 :*: Var "a" :+: Var "b" and use it afterwards . My problem is that I succeded in obtaining " Val 2 :*: Var "a" :+: Var "b" " from the input but now I am stuck as that thing is a string .I just need to find a way to escape " " and use it as a declaration for Expr str . And I am not allowed to use any parser from any library that haskell has.

Comment: At this point you're asking "how to write a Parser", which might be too broad for a SO question.

Comment: Surely your course has taught you something that would indicate roughly what direction to proceed in? Otherwise, this question is much too broad.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you having trouble?

Comment: For this specific expression language, I think you can implement your own parser as a [operator-precedence parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser). You can use a list for your stack. Still, if this is homework, your course should have suggested a specific way to tackle this, and you should follow that suggestion. I can't believe some instructor assigned a parsing problem without covering the basic techniques first, or at least providing some direction.

Comment: A basic partial solution is to add `deriving (Read)` to `Expr` and then call `read` on the result of your “parsing” function. By default it won’t handle precedence; you can implement that by replacing `+` with `)) :+: ((` and `*` with `) :*: (`—fewer parentheses for higher precedence—and wrapping with `((`…`))`. But it won’t handle associativity, so `"Val 1 :+: (Val 2 :+: Val 3)"` and `"(Val 1 :+: Val 2) :+: Val 3"` will read correctly, but `"Val 1 :+: Val 2 :+: Val 3"` will raise an exception. So at this point you should learn how to write a parser, an example of which is in jpath’s answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
import Control.Applicative (Alternative (empty, many, some, (<|>)), (<**>))
import Data.Char           (isSpace, isDigit)
import Data.Maybe          (listToMaybe)
```

Writing a basic, inefficient parsing library is actually not that hard and can be done in under 50 lines of code. The core type looks like this:

```
newtype Parser a = Parser (String -> [(a, String)])

parse :: Parser a -> String -> Maybe a
parse (Parser p) s = listToMaybe $ fst <$> p s
```

This parser partially consumes a string and returns a parsed result `a` along with the remainder string. But there may be many parsing alternatives, which is why it returns a list of results and remainders.

For working with this type we need a few more utilities. I left the `_`s for you to implement.

```
instance Functor Parser where
   fmap (Parser p) = _

instance Applicative Parser where
   pure a = Parser $ \s -> (a, s) -- Consumes nothing and returns a
   Parser pf <*> Parser pa = _    -- Parse pf, then parse pa and apply the result
                                  -- of pf to that of pa.

instance Alternative Parser where
   empty = Parser $ \s -> []   -- Matches nothing
   Parser p1 <|> Parser p2 = _ -- Matches either p1 or if that fails p2.

satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy = _

space :: Parser ()
space = () <$ satisfy isSpace

spaces :: Parser ()
spaces = () <$ many space

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = satisfy (c ==)

-- | Detects the end of file.
eof :: Parser ()
eof = _

-- | Succeeds when at the end of a word, without consuming any input
eow :: Parser ()
eow = _
```

Now we can go ahead and use this parser like any recursive descent parser:

```
data Expr = Val Integer
          | Expr :*: Expr
          | Expr :+: Expr
  deriving Show

parseVal :: Parser Expr
parseVal =
  char '(' *> parseAdd <* char ')' <|>
  Val . read <$> some (satisfy isDigit) <* eow

parseMul :: Parser Expr
parseMul = _

parseAdd :: Parser Expr
parseAdd = _

parseExpr :: Parser Expr
parseExpr = parseAdd <* eof
```